# Получить имена методов

Tags: php

Вывод из var_dump()

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
  ["products"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (32) {
    ["58c81d6dba1aa18e4f5937b5"]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    ["58c81dce97a7071176258006"]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(2)
    }
    ["58c81df797a70711762580f2"]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(3)
    }

  }
  ["shippingId"]=>
  string(24) "58c804f7e73e0f9f5c95eb9b"
  ["paymentId"]=>
  string(24) "58c804f7e73e0f9f5c95eb99"
}
```

Как бы из products получить список имен всех методов там ? Я про 58c81d6dba1aa18e4f5937b5, 58c81dce97a7071176258006 и т.д.

Вариант вроде

```
echo  key($form->products).'<br>';
```

работает только для первого значения, а как дальше перебирать я хз, по аналогии с массивом не работает.

Comment: `array_keys($form->products)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Key** берет только первый ключ элемента массива. Тебе нужно перебрать все элементы через цикл:

```
foreach($form->products as $key => $val){
   echo $key;
}
```

или через функцию **array_keys($form->products)**

Answer (score 1):

**get_class_methods** — Возвращает массив имен методов класса([источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-class-methods.php))

```
$class_methods = get_class_methods(new products());
```